# Elasticsearch RestHighLevelClient bulk operation not working after some time of restart of service

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, buffer, bulkinsert, resthighlevelclient

Elasticsearch RestHighLevelClient bulk operation not working after some time, but initially it works.

This is how our code looks.

```
public BulkResponse bulkOperation(BulkRequest bulkRequest) {

        BulkResponse bulkResponse;
        try {
            bulkResponse = restHighLevelClient.bulk(bulkRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Exception occurred while indexing bulk request data to elastic search index : " + bulkRequest.requests().get(0).index(), e);
            throw new RuntimeException("Error while bulk request index : " + bulkRequest.requests().get(0).index(),e);
        }

        return bulkResponse;
    }
```

Below is how we create Rest client

```
private void init(ElasticSearchConfiguration configuration) {
    HttpHost[] elasticSearchHosts = getElasticSearchHosts(configuration);
    RestClientBuilder builder = RestClient.builder(elasticSearchHosts);
    builder.setRequestConfigCallback(requestConfigBuilder ->
            //Sets a specified timeout value, in milliseconds, to be used when opening a communications link to the resource referenced by this URLConnection.
            // A timeout of -1 is interpreted as an infinite timeout.
            requestConfigBuilder.setConnectTimeout(configuration.getConnectionTimeout())
                    //Sets the socket timeout value. A timeout of -1 is interpreted as an infinite timeout.
                    .setSocketTimeout(configuration.getSocketTimeout())
                    //Set the time to wait for a connection from the connection manager/pool. A timeout of -1 is interpreted as an infinite timeout.
                    .setConnectionRequestTimeout(configuration.getConnectionRequestTimeout()));

    //create the rest high level client using above rest low level client
    restHighLevelClient = new RestHighLevelClient(builder);

    //createIndices(configuration);
}

public HttpHost[] getElasticSearchHosts(ElasticSearchConfiguration elasticSearchConfiguration) {
    List<HttpHost> hosts = new ArrayList<>();
    String esHosts = elasticSearchConfiguration.getHost();
    if (null != esHosts) {
        HashSet<String> hostsSet = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(esHosts.split(",")));
        hostsSet.stream().forEach(s -> {
            hosts.add(HttpHost.create(s));
        });
    }

    HttpHost[] hostsArr = hosts.toArray(new HttpHost[hosts.size()]);
    return hostsArr;
}
```

ES server version :

```
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.10.2",
    "build_flavor" : "oss",
    "build_type" : "rpm",
    "build_hash" : "747e1cc71def077253878a59143c1f785afa92b9",
    "build_date" : "2021-01-13T00:42:12.435326Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "8.7.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
  },
```

Client version : elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-7.5.1.jar.

Our application read messages from Kafka and convert into IndexRequests and save in ElasticSearch, initially all the data indexing works fine after some time it don't work, and there is no error or failure, once we reset Kafka offset and restart the application, it indexes all the data correctly.
Any idea why its happening?

Comment: The issue could be with the document you are trying to index, the mapping of your index and the way you check that the document was indeed inserted. None of this information is present in your question. Can you post a small program that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: Hi there , you'll get solution faster if you share more details

Comment: @FarkhodAbdukodirov added more details please check.

Comment: @imotov please check now.

Comment: What does it mean "after some time it don't work"? You don't get records from Kafka? Or you added some logging and you see that you send requests to elasticsearch and you don't find the records in elasticsearch?

Comment: Yes added logging, can see requests sending to elastic search, but latest updates are not coming in ES.

Comment: So, let's go back to my original question. Can you show how your requests and elasticsearch responses look like when the updates stop appearing in ES? How do you check for these updates?